# Multiple migration plugins

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm creating a custom importer with migrate from json files.
I've several migrate sources for nodes (called: articoli, canti, autori) and one source for comments (called: commenti).

I'm using migration plugin to set relationship between entities, but in the yml for comment how should I set multiples sources?

In [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process/process-plugin-migration) I find this:

```
 process:   
   uid:
     plugin: migration
     migration: 
       - users
       - members
     source_ids: 
       users:
         - author
       members:
         - author
```

I don't understand if migrate cycles for every migration (users, members) using these source_ids and, if matches, goes to next element.